# sprite frame is not rotating in animation

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I want to rotate the third animation frame in my code below when it is run. I am doing this using an `NSNotification` when the frame is displayed to send a message. The animation plays without the third frame rotating. How can I solve this? I guess there could be 'simpler' ways to achieve this but I want to do it using NSNotifications.

```
-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
if( (self=[super init]) ) {

CCSpriteBatchNode* batchNode;
CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache;

frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
[frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"cat-hd.plist"];
batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"cat-hd.pvr.ccz"];

[self addChild:batchNode];

CCSprite* wallbg = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"firstBg.png"];
wallbg.position= ccp(240.0, 160.0);

//wallbg.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
[batchNode addChild:wallbg];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotateAnimationFrame:) name:CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification object:nil];

NSMutableArray* catAnimationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) // i< number of frames in the plist File Name
{
    CCLOG(@"item %d added", i);
    [catAnimationArray addObject:
     [frameCache spriteFrameByName:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blackCat%d.png", i]]];    }

CCSprite* catSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: @"blackCat1.png"];

CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
catSprite.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);

CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:catAnimationArray delay:0.6];

repeatMovement = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation :animation]];
    [catSprite runAction:repeatMovement];

    //CCAnimationFrame* thirdAnim = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:@"catAnim3.png"];
    CCRotateTo *rotateRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.3 angle:40.0];
    rotateSprite = [catSprite runAction:rotateRight];

    [batchNode addChild:catSprite];

    NSDictionary* theInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:rotateSprite,@"rotateSprite", nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification object:self userInfo:theInfo];

    CCAnimationFrame* thirdFrame = [animation.frames objectAtIndex:2];

    thirdFrame.userInfo = theInfo;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotateAnimationFrame:) name:CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification object:nil];

}

return self;

}



-(void)rotateAnimationFrame:(NSNotification*)notification {

    CCAction  *rotateAction = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"rotateSprite"];

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever actually run your rotate action. You need a [node runAction:rotate];

Comment: ok, I think I get the idea

Comment: Is the code you have posted for -(void)rotateAnimationFrame:(NSNotification*)notification complete? You need to actually run the animation in that method. Also using notifications for this is a bad idea.

Comment: should the animation be run on the `catSprite`? I also had a feeling that there would be alternative ways to achieve this but because I'll be incorporating a lot of frame by frame changes in my game I decided to just get used to using notifications.

Comment: Yes you need to run the action on the sprite you want to rotate.

Comment: In fact reading your code some more, this won't work. Your notification is going to fire once when you setup the animation. It won't fire per frame.

Comment: I am mainly interested in the rotating the third frame for now. What other issues do I have with my code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33522/discussion-between-nscodeman-and-ben-trengrove)

Comment: @BenTrengrove: I am still trying to get it solved. I haven't made much headway.